# Inverse of the Modified Bessel function

Tags: calculus, inverse, bessel-functions

Is there any chance of having a formula or approximation to inverse the Modified Bessel function of the first kind? I mean to solve $I_M(x)$ with respect to x: $I^{-1}_M(x)$?

Answer (score 2):

I've come across a more precise method, in Mathematica you can use

InverseSeries[Series[BesselI[0,x],{x,0,20}]]

which gives \begin{equation}
2\sqrt{x-1}-\frac{1}{4}(x-1)^{3/2}+\frac{47}{576}(x-1)^{5/2}-\frac{161}{4608}(x-1)^{7/2}+\frac{565571}{33177600}(x-1)^{9/2}-\cdots
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of $I_0(x)$ closely follows $\cosh(x)$, \begin{equation}
I_0(x)=1+\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^4}{64}+\frac{x^6}{2304}+\cdots,\\
\cosh(x)=1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+\frac{x^6}{720}+\cdots,
\end{equation}

so you could take inspiration from an expansion of $\mathrm{acosh}(x)$ about $x=1$,
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{acosh}(x)=\sqrt{2} \sqrt{x-1}-\frac{(x-1)^{3/2}}{6 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{3 (x-1)^{5/2}}{80\sqrt{2}}-\frac{5(x-1)^{7/2}}{448 \sqrt{2}}+\cdots,
\end{equation}
and find some coefficients $a_n$
\begin{equation}
I^{-1}_0(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(x-1)^{(2n-1)/2}
\end{equation}
By fitting some values from an appropriate root finder (Wolfram|Alpha will do) with a truncated series the first few terms appear to be \begin{equation}
a_1=2\\
a_2=-\frac{1}{4}
\end{equation}
Below are the results of a parameter fitting from $\mathrm{gnuplot}$.
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
a_1      &          2            &    \pm 6.13\cdot10^{-8}     \\
a_2      &          -0.249991     &   \pm 1.3\cdot10^{-6}      \\
a_3      &          0.0815024     &   \pm 8.409\cdot10^{-6}    \\
a_4      &          -0.0345023    &   \pm 2.578\cdot10^{-5}    \\
a_5      &          0.0159056     &   \pm 4.474\cdot10^{-5}    \\
a_6      &          -0.00706415   &   \pm 4.802\cdot10^{-5}    \\
a_7      &          0.00270988    &  \pm3.337\cdot10^{-5}    \\
a_8      &          -0.000821109  &   \pm 1.528\cdot10^{-5}    \\
a_9      &          0.000182402   &   \pm 4.578\cdot10^{-6}    \\
a_{10}      &          -2.74386\cdot10^{-5}  &   \pm 8.628\cdot10^{-7}    \\
a_{11}      &          2.47422\cdot10^{-6}   &   \pm 9.278\cdot10^{-8}    \\
a_{12}      &          -1.00428\cdot10^{-7}  &   \pm 4.339\cdot10^{-9}    
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}
we can set these first two values and then fit again \begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
a_3      &          0.0814389    &    \pm 7.448\cdot10^{-6}   \\
a_4       &         -0.0340809   &    \pm 2.745\cdot10^{-5}  \\
a_5        &        0.0150122     &   \pm 4.322\cdot10^{-5}   \\
a_6        &        -0.00607734  &    \pm 3.866\cdot10^{-5}   \\
a_7        &        0.00205892     &  \pm 2.205\cdot10^{-5}  \\
a_8        &        -0.000552547  &   \pm 8.5\cdot10^{-6}    \\
a_9        &        0.000113841   &   \pm 2.285\cdot10^{-6}  \\
a_{10}        &        -1.76097\cdot10^{-5}  &   \pm 4.334\cdot10^{-7}   \\
a_{11}        &        1.99748\cdot10^{-6}   &  \pm 5.785\cdot10^{-8}    \\
a_{12}        &        -1.6062\cdot10^{-7}   &   \pm 5.316\cdot10^{-9}    \\
a_{13}        &        8.64948\cdot10^{-9}   &   \pm 3.203\cdot10^{-10}   \\
a_{14}        &        -2.79347\cdot10^{-10}   &  \pm 1.139\cdot10^{-11}  \\
a_{15}        &        4.08662\cdot10^{-12}   &  \pm 1.812\cdot10^{-13}  
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}

This expansion of $I^{-1}_0(x)$ seems worst case accurate up to $\varepsilon=\pm 1.2\cdot10^{-6}$ in the interval $[0,10]$, (see residues plot).

[Residues of the series fitting against sampled values of $I^{-1}_0(x)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur6iB.png)