# Coefficients of the Inverse Modified Bessel Function

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics, inverse-function

I am curious if there is a closed form that represents the coefficients of the inverse of the modified Bessel function of the first kind $I_{0}(x)$. I can find the series representation using InverseSeries[Series[BesselI[0,x],{x,0,20}]] in Mathematica.

$$I^{-1}_{0}(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{(-1)^{n+1}a_{n}(x-1)^{n-\frac{1}{2}}}$$

The first few coefficients $a_{n}$ are: $2$, $\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{47}{576}$, $\frac{161}{4608}$, $\frac{565571}{33177600}$, $...$ Or the series can be expressed as:
$$I^{-1}_{0}(x)=2\sqrt{x-1}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}{(-1)^{n}b_{n}(x-1)^{n}}$$

In this case, the coefficients would just be divided by two: $1$, $\frac{1}{8}$, $\frac{47}{1152}$, $\frac{161}{9216}$, $\frac{565571}{66355200}$, $...$ Other than the coefficients, the inverse Bessel function is very similar to the $\cosh^{-1}(x)$ series. If there is no closed form, or neat closed form for either of the coefficients $a_{n}$ or $b_{n}$, is there a better way, or more condensed way to represent these sums?

Comment: A similar question is from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694282/inverse-of-the-modified-bessel-function). Inverses of most special functions usually have [complicated forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703913/finding-an-inverse-for-clausen-functions). However, you can [find](https://randorithms.com/2021/08/31/Taylor-Series-Inverse.html) a recurrence relation. You could also represent the coefficients as an $n$th derivative, like in a Taylor series, but that may not be satisfying